# How to vertically align Text in the middle with an Image in the same HTML Table Cell

Tags: html, html-table

[Here's the Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVEAm.png)

I'm struggling to vertically align text with an image within the same HTML cell that they share. I'm sharing a simpler version of the test html file I created, but in the past I've tried everything from CSS and nested tables but somehow couldn't get it to work. Appreciate the help.

CSS:

```
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 25%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Col-1</th>
            <th>Col-2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="Star.png" style="width:60px">  Static Text</td>
          <td>Static Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Use `vertical-align: middle;` on the image. It will push the text to the center as well.

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9mw03sp/)

Also if I were you I wouldn't use inline CSS. It can give problems in future, use instead an external CSS file

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for, really appreciate the quick and accurate response.

This is what I did:
<td><img src="Star.png" width="60px" style="vertical-align:middle">  Static Text</td>

Comment: @Rocky you can do it like that but inline CSS can cuz problems in the future

Comment: Thank you.  I moved it to the external CSS file, now it works.